# Why is json data used among different components synchronised?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I'm working on building an angular application. From what i have observed, if i pass the same json data to different components using an observable, changing the json in one component is reflected in the other components as well. I have found a work around for this, by stringfying and parsing data in any component, the sync is broken. But i still don't understand why the json is in sync among all the components it is passed to.

EDIT:

So I have two components `CapabilityTreeComponent` and `FDCTreeViewComponent`.

Basically they contain d3 tree diagrams.
Initially both components use the same json data to build the d3 tree. That is, same data is passed through different observables.

When i add a new node to the d3, i passed data to both `FDCTreeViewComponent` and `CapabilityTreeComponent` since i thought both were different components and they had to have separate methods to add the new node in their respective trees.

But the nodes were getting added twice in both components.

Comment: It's probably the same object instance

Comment: Try to provide some specific [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As of now, your question is very broad.

Comment: Oh. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @Rawrplus give me a minute

Comment: This [article](https://ngravi.com/understanding-angulars-onpush-change-detection-strategy/) could be of help :)